# aysnc task from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, appdelegate

I am writing little SDK which going to play movie and show some advertisements etc.

In general concept has completed which i am calling UIViewController as modalViewController and it's playing and showing advertisements in UIView successful. My main concept is tied up with UIView container. In that container , MPMoviePlayer.view and other UIWebView added in subview.

I need to call that UIView ( Not Call UIViewController as modal ) and show in current viewcontroller's UIView as expected. With that future, user will going to see movie and scroll the app and use other futures at the same time like Facebook .

The problem is , when i call Player's class parameter which has trigger to play option, class  is disappeared asap . ( Because of lots of async works firing in same time and  callbacks ( NSNotificationCenter ) ) need to catch scenario in order to play Video or Advertisement.

How I am suppose to call Player Class's UIView from another UIviewController and keep persistent connection between 2 UIViewControllers  for Async Connection and MPMoviePlayer .

At the beginning of my scenario, I cannot implement all these scenario in Developer UIViewController because it will be SDK ( will be closed , only header files going to be seen )

I hope i could explained my scenario clearly,

Best Regards.

Onder.

Comment: Really not clear what your asking about here.  Take a look at [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) from Apple on container view controllers.

Comment: I need to call VideoPlayerViewController UIView to another UIViewController's UIView such as keeping address But  VideoPlayerViewController has some async tasks which is does not handled by GDC i think it does not wait to finish async tasks.